# How to get posts images from RSS?

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, rss, feed

I want to get posts thumbnails from RSS feeds, But the code doesn't contain the images.

It looks like:

```
<rss xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <title></title>
        <link></link>
        <description>Main feed</description>
        <language>is-IS</language>
        <pubDate>Wed, 27 Jun 2018 02:47:24 GMT</pubDate>
        <docs>http://blogs.law.harvard.edu/tech/rss</docs>
        <ttl>100</ttl>
        <generator>RSS</generator>

        <item>
            <title></title>
            <description>
                <![CDATA[

                ]]>
            </description>
            <link></link>
            <guid/>
            <pubDate>Tue, 26 Jun 2018 12:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

Is there is a way to get the images? They exist on the news page as thumbnails.

Comment: Kindly post some code also on which you are working

Answer (score 0):

However you haven't post your code Simple Code Will be like this: 
**if any confusion please ask**

**[Documentation at PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php)**

**php file**

```
<?php
  $xml =simplexml_load_file('read.xml');
  echo $xml->channel->title;
  echo '<br/>';
  echo $xml->channel->link;  
?>
```

**xml file(changed little bit just added content)**

```
<rss xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="2.0">
<channel>
    <title>title is here</title>
    <link>link is here</link>
    <description>Main feed</description>
    <language>is-IS</language>
    <pubDate>Wed, 27 Jun 2018 02:47:24 GMT</pubDate>
    <docs>http://blogs.law.harvard.edu/tech/rss</docs>
    <ttl>100</ttl>
    <generator>RSS</generator>

    <item>
        <title></title>
        <description>
            <![CDATA[

            ]]>
        </description>
        <link></link>
        <guid/>
        <pubDate>Tue, 26 Jun 2018 12:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
    </item>
</channel>
```

[image]

Comment: @ashley does it helped

Comment: Thanks, But I know how to get these data, I want to get the image

Comment: In the original posts, They all have images(thumbnails), But in each item that image doesn't exist

Comment: but can you tell me where is image or in which tag you are having image????

Comment: That's what I'm talking about, It doesn't exist in each item

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to get the post's image, we can do that - presuming there is an image in the post's content/body. Here's what I would do.

I created a package to make xml parsing a breeze. You can find it here: https://github.com/mtownsend5512/xml-to-array

Then do the following:

```
$xml = \Mtownsend\XmlToArray\XmlToArray::convert(file_get_contents('https://www.yourrssfeed.com'));
```

Now you have a nice php array of the rss feed.

Next, we will create a helper function to get the first image out of the post's body. We'll use this as the post's featured image.

```
function getPostImage($content)
{
    $output = preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"][^>]*>/i', $content, $matches);
    if (empty($matches[1][0])) {
        return 'http://yoursite.com/images/fallback-image.jpg';
    }
    return $matches[1][0];
}
```

You'll want to replace `http://yoursite.com/images/fallback-image.jpg` with the url to your fallback image if there is no image in the post.

Now, we loop through the posts:

```
foreach ($xml['channel']['item'] as $post) {
    $title = $post['title']);
    $link = $post['link'];
    $description = $post['description'];
    $pubDate = $post['pubDate'];
    $image = getPostImage($post["content:encoded"]);
}
```

Hope that helps.